# Why is scandir() returning false for directories?

Tags: php

I have a directory named `client_images` that has `dir_1`, `dir_2` and `dir_3` as subdirectories.  When i run the following:

```
foreach(scandir("client_images") as $key => $value ){
    if(is_dir($value)){
        echo $value." is a dir.<br>";
    }
    else{
        echo $value." is not a dir.<br>";
    }
}
```

i get :

> ```
> . is a dir.
> .. is a dir.
> dir_1 is not a dir.
> dir_2 is not a dir.
> dir_3 is not a dir.
> ```

Why is php returning false for directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `scandir("client_images")`; the result is bare filenames *without* the `client_images/` path, so it's looking for them in the current directory.  Naturally, the only directories likely to be in common between `.`. and `client_images/` are `.` and `..`, the entries present in all directories.

Comment: Thanks, so how to check for dirs inside client_images?

Comment: Prepend `"client_images/"` (or Windows equivalent) to the path passed to `is_dir()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$mydir = "client_images/";

foreach(scandir($mydir) as $key => $value ){
  if(is_dir($mydir . $value)){
    echo $value." is a dir.<br>";
    }
  else{
    echo $value." is not a dir.<br>";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can scan directory using [DirectoryIterators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php). Use the below code to to check if a file is a directory or not

```
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator('path');
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isDir()) {
        echo $fileinfo->getFilename() . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution was promising, but in 2021 it did not work and threw debug errors in PHP 7.4.26. Posting for anyone who lands here like I did.